# Redux form submit validation with redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-thunk

In my form, I'm trying to check email by using reactive-thunk to determine if the email address was already received. Everything is working properly, except for one thing. I request the api and I'm sending the data to the reducer, but the component I have access to the state is empty. Because the state value in the component is working before the reducer.

Is there any help of how to do that?

Submit.js

```
onSubmit = data => {
    const { saveUser, validateEmail, emailValidate } = this.props;
    validateEmail(data.email); // action create for api request
    console.log(emailValidate); // fetch data in reducer(This data is empty because code run before reducer set state)
    if (emailValidate.statusMessage === 'OK') {
      throw new SubmissionError({ email: 'Email already in use', _error: 'Login failed!' });
    } else {

    }
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    validateEmail(email) {
      dispatch(validateEmail(email));
    },
  };
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  emailValidate: state.registrationFormEmailValidate.data,
});
```

Comment: Why not use the validator as an async blur validator since you're using redux form? Or is there any particular reason you want to validate the email upon submission instead?

More on async blur validation here - https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/asyncvalidation/

Answer (score 0):

```
onSubmit = data => {
  const { saveUser, validateEmail, emailValidate } = this.props;
  validateEmail(data.email); // action create for api request
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.emailValidate.statusMessage !== prevProps.emailValidate.statusMessage) {
    console.log(this.props.emailValidate);
    if (this.props.emailValidate.statusMessage === 'OK') {
      throw new SubmissionError({ email: 'Email already in use', _error: 'Login failed!' });
    } else {

    }
  }
}
```

If you are using `class component`, you can use `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: When SubmissionError outside of the submit function gives an error